# Change default build variant in Android Studio Hedgehog

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Since updated Android Studio to Hedgehog (2023.1.1) on startup the build variant is reset to the default – the one shown as "(default)" in the "Build Variants" side menu. Is there a way to set another build variant as default.

This would be helpful since the one specified as default is the one I nearly never use and switching takes some time or sometimes I even accidentally build the wrong variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the instruction getIsDefault().set(true):

Here's an example to set the flavor2 as default:

For **DSL**

```
buildTypes {
  flavor2 {
    getIsDefault().set(true)
  }
  ...
}
```

For **KTS**

```
productFlavors {
        create("flavor2") {
            isDefault = true
            ......
        }
        ....
}
```